# Administration menu escaped

Tags: joomla-3.x

I did something wrong with my joomla based page. When I go to /administration/ I have only message:

```
There are important post-installation messages that require your attention. To view those messages please click on the Review Messages button below.

You can review the messages at any time by clicking on the Components, Post-installation messages menu item of your site's Administrator section. This information area won't appear when you have hidden all messages.
```

And no more any buttons and menus. How to get back administration environment?

Comment: This message occour after install some component, module or plugin? If yes, you can access your database and "disable" last installed in table #_extensions change enable colum to 0.

Answer (score 1):

1) Create and download a backup:
[www.ostraining.com/blog/joomla/test-site-akeeba-backup/](http://www.ostraining.com/blog/joomla/test-site-akeeba-backup/)

2) Fix your folder and file permission using Ad min Tools:
https://www.ostraining.com/blog/joomla/admin-tools-the-quick-and-easy-way-to-change-folder-and-file-permissions/

3) Download an update for your Joomla version:
[https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/releases](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/releases/download/3.5.1/Joomla_3.5.1-Stable-Update_Package.zip)

then install it from Extensions >> Extension Manager , as you would an extension.

4) Go to Extensions >> Extension Manager >> Database >> Fix

That should reset all your core files to 3.4.1 as well as your database.

5) Clear your browser's cache as well as your site cache.

Answer (score 0):

Or simple run the sql

`UPDATE #__assets SET rules = '{"core.login.site":{"6":1,"2":1},"core.login.admin":{"6":1},"core.login.offline":{"6":1},"core.admin":{"8":1},"core.manage":{"7":1},"core.create":{"6":1,"3":1},"core.delete":{"6":1},"core.edit":{"6":1,"4":1},"core.edit.state":{"6":1,"5":1},"core.edit.own":{"6":1,"3":1}}' WHERE id = 1`

It will reset you core permissions

Oh, and if this will not help - check if your Super Users group have `id = 8` - it's default at `#__usergroups`

And you may also check if your user in this user group by checking `#__user_usergroup_map` table. Columns names speak for them selves.